# Fixed header overlapping page content

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image]

The section under my fixed position headed is being overlapped slightly by the header instead of being flush with it. The top of the carousel should sit immediately under the bottom of the header so that it fills the entire screen minus the header size.

The html consists of 3 's within the body, a sticky header and a footer that does not move.

```
body{
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.header{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #0d0d0d;
  height: 65px
}

section {
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100vh - 65px);
  scroll-snap-align: center;
}

.splash-carousel{
  height: calc(100vh - 65px);
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: @mahan I removed the position: sticky part, that was a remnant from an early attempted fix. Yes I am fairly sure that the header is 65px, the carousel height is calculated based on that value, and as the picture shows, it should fit perfectly under the header, its just being misaligned for some reason.

Comment: You have used fixed-top which sets postition of the header to fixed and then why are you setting again its position to sticky ? Are you sure that the header is 65px?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed-top removes `nav` from the normal flow of the content. And its the section that takes its place. You need to set either `margin-top` of the `section` or set `padding-top` of body to `56px` so that the `section` becomes fully visible.

Bootstrap-4 nav's original height is `56px`. Regardless of it, you should self find and calculate it.

```
 body {
  padding-top: 56px;
}
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 56px;
}


.full-screen {
  height: calc(100vh - 56px) !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <main class="container-fluid ">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col bg-primary full-screen">
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZdMjMX

As you see it works in the codepen. If it does not work for you, the problem is either the heade's height is more than `65px` or the image is too big. Try  not using the image and see if it is the cause.

Comment: This doesn't work for smaller screens when navbar collapsed/expand. Also if we have a dynamically created drop-down in the top navbar how do you decide the height of the navbar?